# What are the tools that aid accurate tiller-steering in large airliners?

Tags: taxiing

Airliners often need to make rather tight turns at airports. It's difficult enough maneuvering around small obstacles in a car if they can't be seen, and that's with the benefit of a good awareness of the positions of wheels, good visibility, etc. This must be much more difficult in an airliner.

For example, at a T, how do you know how far you need to stick your nose into the grass before you start turning, to keep reasonably close to the centreline? Is it just a matter of expertise and experience, or are there hi-tch gadgets or maybe lo-tech marks and sight-lines which help maneuverer these elephants around?

Comment: Def a dup. Sorry. I did do a fair bit of searching first!